# How to get an entity's key on google datastore

Tags: key, entity, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to the Google App Engine Datastore and I'm having trouble understanding the entity keys.  I have been letting the datastore automatically assign a key to entities.  What I want to do is retrieve an entity's key in order to pass it as a parameter to another method.  Is there a way to get it without manually setting a key when I add the entity to the database.  I have so far been looking up entities by a function I wrote that gets a user from the database by querying for their specific email address.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43384636/5890175

Answer (score 0):

use the key() method.

For example if you have an instance photo of the class Photo, then you can retrieve the key by photo.key()